# Can't find my registered Azure AD Applications

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to configure multi-tenant authentication with Azure App Service in order to enable multi-tenant authentication for my application. I'm following this tutorial: [Consume multi-tenant enterprise APIs secured with Azure AD in SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient-enterpriseapi-multitenant). But I got stuck while I'm configuring Authentication / Authorization settings.

[image: Unable to find applications]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [Configure your App Service app to use Azure Active Directory login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad) to configure an Azure App to use Azure AD as a authentication provider. While selecting an existing app on express settings you need to make sure the app is registered within your tenant. You can also refer to [How to Get to the Keys/Secrets From Azure Active Directory](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaddevsup/2018/04/25/how-to-get-to-the-keyssecrets-from-azure-active-directory/) to get the keys/secrets from Azure AD for an Enterprise Application.